# Rails 3 - Accessing sort value in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table which needs column wise sorting, there will be up/down arrow images on each of the headers, when its clicked the control passes to the javascript file which returns the sorting value to the function in the controller and the sorting should be done.Below are some of the code for reference.

Index.html.erb

```
  <input type="hidden" id = "sort" value="<%= @sort %>">
      <% if @sort == 1 %>
          <img id="sort_no" src="<%=asset_path('sales_info_management/down_normal.gif')%>">
      <% else %>
          <img id="sort_no" src="<%=asset_path('sales_info_management/up_active.gif')%>">
      <% end %
```

details_controller.rb

```
def itemize
 @details = Detail.all
 @sort = 0

 respond_to do |format|
   format.html # itemize.html.erb
   format.json { render :json => @details }
 end
end

def sort
 @sort = params["sort_type"].to_i

 respond_to do |format|
   format.html
 end
end
```

sort.js

```
function sort_sales_informations(path){
  var params = new Array();
  var sort = $('#sort').val();
  sort = sort == 0 ? 1 : 0
  params['sort_type'] = sort;
  path = build_url(path, params);
  $.get(path, function(data) {
 });
}
```

At present after changing the sort value from the javascript file am not being able to pass it to the form where <%= @sort %> is being used.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns) for a good solution.

Comment: Thanks! but i need a solution for what i have posted.

Comment: Surely you could apply the logic from the railscast to what you have posted?

Comment: Thanks Charles & Tango for ur comments but i need a solution for what i have posted.